# Multiselect in Spring data Jpa CriteraQuery not giving expected result

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, predicate, criteria-api

I have one entity as Project and I am writing one jpa specification for implementing pagination. Now the problem is I don't want whole entity,I just want some columns of that entity.
My specification looks like -

```
public class ProjectSpecification {

    public static Specification<Project> projectListSearchSpec(Set<Long> deptIdList, SearchDto searchDTO) {
        return new Specification<Project>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Project> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                query.multiselect(root.get("id"));
                Predicate all = root.<Project>get("department").get("departmentId").in(deptIdList);
                return all;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

As it can be seen in the snippet that I am trying to use multi-select but there is nor effect of that. 
I am still getting all the attributes of entity.